# Objective-C: How can I remove just one subview from UIWindow?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, uiwindow

I want to remove just 1 subview not all.
And That subview is UIWebView.

Comment: May I know who is in trouble? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try this if you do not declare an instance var in your header file.

```
for(UIView *view in window.subViews){

  if([view isKindOfClass[UIWebView class]]){
     [view removeFromSuperview];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can call this on the `UIWebView` you want to remove:

```
[myWebView removeFromSuperview];
```

[This method is available to all subclasses of `UIView` and `NSView`.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, if you don't have a reference to it, just give a tag when you created it like this

```
myWebView.tag = 1234;
```

And remove it like this

```
[[myParentView viewWithTag:1234] removeFromSuperview]
```